# R - How to test for character(0) in IF statement

Tags: r, if-statement

I imagine this is incredibly simple but I cant seem to find the answer.

I am writing an IF statement but the test is if the object returns a `character(0)` value. I am not sure how to deal with `character(0)` in the statement.

Assuming `Test <- character(0)` or a value:

```
if (identical(Pols4,character(0))) {
  print('Empty')
} else {
  print('Not Empty')
}
```

It still does not seem to work.....

Comment: `length(character(0))` is zero, so `if (length(x))` should do.

Comment: No sorry, it does not. `length(NULL)` is also zero, and `length(numeric(0))` too.

Comment: Changing your first line to `if(identical(Test, character(0)))` didn't work?

Comment: the if else statement throws an Error : unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: Whats `Pols4`?? It works for `Test`

Answer (score 132):

Use the `identical` function to check this.

```
a <- character(0)
identical(a, character(0))  # returns TRUE

identical(a, "")           # returns FALSE
identical(a, numeric(0))   # returns also FALSE
```

Comment: I was still getting a `FALSE` return until I used `identical(a,as.Date(character(0))` because the value showed as `character(0)` even after I had cast the result as a date earlier in my code.

Comment: If you cast a value to Date, then it's not identical to `character(0)`, so this behavior is perfectly fine. `quote(character(0))` is also displayed as `character(0)` in the console and definitively not identical to `character(0)`.

Comment: I was not complaining. I was just sharing in case others have a similar case.

Comment: out of curiosity, why does `a == character(0)`  return `logical(0)` instead of returning `TRUE`

Comment: Because `==` works vectorwise (cf. `c("a","b")==c("a","c")` returning `c(TRUE,FALSE)`) and `character(0)` is a "vector of type 'character' of length 0" (cf. `c("a", character(0))` is identical to `"a"`). Hence a "vector of type 'logical' of length 0" is a sound result.

Answer (score 28):

Adding the obligatory tidyverse answer. The `rlang` package has the function `is_empty()`, which does exactly what you want.

```
Test <- character(0)
rlang::is_empty(Test)
#[1] TRUE
```

This also works for empty vectors that aren't characters. For example, it works in the case that Patrick Roocks describes in comments.

```
Test <- as.Date(character(0))
rlang::is_empty(Test)
#[1] TRUE
```

Loading the 'tidyverse' package also loads `is_empty()`.

Comment: `is_empty()` is also in `purrr`

Answer (score 9):

Use the length() method:

```
> check <- function(value) {
+ if (length(value)==0) {
+ print('Empty')
+ } else {
+ print('Not Empty')
+ }
+ }
> check("Hello World")
[1] "Not Empty"
> check("")
[1] "Not Empty"
> check(character(0))
[1] "Empty"
```

Answer (score 9):

Many people forget that functions like `str_locate_all()` require `%>% unlist()` or `%>% .[[1]]`.

Then you can easily detect `character(0)` with the `length()` function `if > 0` one can safely use the output of `str_locate_all()` for example.

**Example:**

```
value <- str_extract_all("kvk :", ascii_digit(8,8)) %>% unlist()
if (length(value) > 0) {
  # Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of `length()`, worked for me `nrows()`

Answer (score 1):

My method to solve this problem is dealing with that column only by cast it into a character again
and find "character(0)" instead.

For example:

```
df$interest_column <- as.character(df$interest_column) # Cast it into a character again
df[df$interest_column == "character(0)","interest_column"] <- NA  # Assign new value
```

I hope this is a solution you have asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing some micro-optimization today for a related problem: checking if a numeric vector is empty (e.g. equivalent to `numeric(0)`) when it can either be empty or have a value (it is never `NA` or `NULL`). In my problem the check occurs hundreds of millions of time, so it seemed reasonable to benchmark the right approach. Length benchmarks quite a bit better than other options:

```r
vec = numeric(0)

bench::mark(
  x = { !length(vec) },
  y = { rlang::is_empty(vec) },
  z = { identical(vec, numeric(0)) },
  check = FALSE,
  min_time = 5,
  min_iterations = 100000,
  max_iterations = 100000
)
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` `gc/sec`  n_gc
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 x             200ns    300ns  3621037.     0        0
2 y             5.2us    5.8us   166594.     8.33     5
3 z             1.3us    1.5us   618090.    12.4      2
```

Length checking beating identical checking by 6x and by is_empty by 4x over that. The results for the case where the vector is non-empty are similar, so irrespective of the distribution of your data, just use length.

I am cognizant that there are probably edge cases where the behaviours of these three functions aren't identical, but if like me it's just a matter of a value being either `c(some, number)` or `numeric(0)` and you want to quickly check which, use `length`.