# Unlist a column while retaining character(0) as empty strings in R

Tags: r, list, text, character, na

I am relatively new to R. I have a dataframe that has a column stored as a list. My column contain `c("Benzo", "Ferri")` or `character(0)` if it's empty. How can I change them to simply `Benzo, Ferri` and an empty string for character(0) instead?

I'm not able to, for instance `df$general_RN <- unlist(df$general_RN)` because `Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, general_RN, value = c("Drug Combinations", : replacement has 1992 rows, data has 10479`

I am assuming that all the `character(0)` have been removed but I need them retained as `NA`s.

Here is what the column looks like

```
general_RN
c("Chlorambucil", "Vincristine", "Cyclophosphamide")
Pentazocine
character(0)
character(0)
c("Ampicillin", "Trimethoprim")
character(0)
```

I have ashamedly spent an hour on this problem.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example of your data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - How to test for character(0) in IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640161/r-how-to-test-for-character0-in-if-statement)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's tough to say without more information about your data, but maybe this can be a solution for you, or at least point you into the right direction:

```
a <- list('A',character(0),'B')

> a
[[1]]
[1] "A"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "B"

> unlist(lapply(a,function(x) if(identical(x,character(0))) ' ' else x))
[1] "A" " " "B"
```

So in your case that should be:

```
df$general_RN <- unlist(lapply(df$general_RN,function(x) if(identical(x,character(0))) ' ' else x))
```

HTH

Comment: yikes this almost worked but it only keeps the first element of each list when I want all of it retained

Comment: That's a problem with `ifelse`. Taking a conventional `if else` clause should do the trick. Please see my edits

Comment: thanks. however, that gives me this error `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, general_RN, value = c(" ", " ", " ",  : 
  replacement has 11066 rows, data has 10479` I don't know how or why the replacement has more rows than the data...

Comment: Looking at the example of your column, it's clear that after unlisting you'll have more values than rows in the columns. A vector of 3 strings will be taking 3 individual rows in the end. What you could do is combining the individual stings to a single one with the "words" separated by spaces or similar

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I know how to do that...could you guide me?

Comment: Just substitute the `x` after `else` with `paste0(x,collapse=' ')`. You can also use a comma or another separator in `collapse`. This should do it