# Why does only `case_when` give different results in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I noticed this behavior below when
I used `dplyr::case_when` instead of `if` in reference to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640161/r-how-to-test-for-character0-in-if-statement).
If the output of the second branch is an explicit string, it works as intended, but if the `x` itself is specified, the result changes.

Why does only `case_when` give different results?

```r
x <- character(0)

dplyr::case_when(rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "Empty", !rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "Not empty")
#> [1] "Empty"
dplyr::case_when(rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "Empty", !rlang::is_empty(x) ~ x)
#> character(0)

if (rlang::is_empty(x)) "Empty" else if (!rlang::is_empty(x)) "Not empty"
#> [1] "Empty"
if (rlang::is_empty(x)) "Empty" else if (!rlang::is_empty(x)) x
#> [1] "Empty"

ifelse(rlang::is_empty(x), "Empty", "Not empty")
#> [1] "Empty"
ifelse(rlang::is_empty(x), "Empty", x)
#> [1] "Empty"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Note: `dplyr`s `if_else`-function throws an error: `if_else(purrr::is_empty(x), "Empty", x)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely a bug in `case_when` or its internal helper functions.
We can put a `browser` in the source code of `case_when` to see what happens in both cases. Some internal functions must be called via `:::`.

```
f <- function (...) {
    browser()
    fs <- dplyr:::compact_null(rlang::list2(...))
    n <- length(fs)
    error_call <- rlang::current_env()
    if (n == 0) {
        abort("No cases provided.", call = error_call)
    }
    query <- vector("list", n)
    value <- vector("list", n)
    default_env <- rlang::caller_env()
    quos_pairs <- purrr::map2(fs, seq_along(fs), dplyr:::validate_formula, default_env = default_env, 
                                                        dots_env = rlang::current_env(), error_call = error_call)
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
        pair <- quos_pairs[[i]]
        query[[i]] <- rlang::eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env)
        value[[i]] <- rlang::eval_tidy(pair$rhs, env = default_env)
        if (!is.logical(query[[i]])) {
            dplyr:::abort_case_when_logical(pair$lhs, i, query[[i]], 
                                                                            error_call = error_call)
        }
    }
    m <- dplyr:::validate_case_when_length(query, value, fs, error_call = error_call)
    out <- value[[1]][rep(NA_integer_, m)]
    replaced <- rep(FALSE, m)
    for (i in seq_len(n)) {
        out <- dplyr:::replace_with(out, query[[i]] & !replaced, value[[i]], 
                                                NULL, error_call = error_call)
        replaced <- replaced | (query[[i]] & !is.na(query[[i]]))
    }
    out
}
```

and the helper internal `replace_with` in `dplyr`,

```
replacer <- function (x, i, val, name, reason = NULL, error_call = rlang::caller_env()) {
    if (is.null(val)) {
        return(x)
    }
    dplyr:::check_length(val, x, name, reason, error_call = error_call)
    dplyr:::check_type(val, x, name, error_call = error_call)
    dplyr:::check_class(val, x, name, error_call = error_call)
    i[is.na(i)] <- FALSE
    if (length(val) == 1L) {
        x[i] <- val
    }
    else {
        x[i] <- val[i]
    }
    x
}
```

and then debug via

```
x <- character(0)
f(rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "Empty", !rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "x")
f(rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "Empty", !rlang::is_empty(x) ~ x)
```

the key is in value `m`, that in the working case results in `1L`, in the faulty case it is `0L`. `out` becomes `character(0)` instead of initializing to `NA`, length 1.

`replaced` should be a logical vector indicating whether a value has been replaced. In the faulty case `rep(FALSE, 0L)` is `logical(0)`, which is queried later on via `!replaced`. `FALSE & logical(0)` gives `logical(0)`.

When passed to `replacer` this gives a peculiar subsetting action `character(0)[logical(0)]`, that gives `character(0)`.

Answer (score 4):

This is because `case_when` tries to recycle all formulas to a common length. The documentation says:

> Both LHS and RHS may have the same length of either 1 or n. The value of n must be consistent across all cases. The case of n == 0 is treated as a variant of n != 1.

In your second example you've supplied a 0-length vector as the RHS of one of the formulas and this is the reason that a 0-length vector is returned; it's just a coincidence that the value returned is the same as the RHS of false case.

This behaviour might seem less surprising when considering these examples:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

case_when(TRUE ~ 1, FALSE ~ numeric(0))
#> numeric(0)

case_when(TRUE ~ 1, FALSE ~ numeric(1))
#> [1] 1

case_when(TRUE ~ 1, FALSE ~ numeric(2))
#> [1] 1 1

case_when(TRUE ~ 1, FALSE ~ numeric(3))
#> [1] 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

One big difference between `case_when` and `ifelse` is that `case_when` coerces the right-hand side arguments into the same type. From `?case_when`:

> The RHS does not need to be logical, but all RHSs must evaluate to the
> same type of vector.

It might also throw errors.

```
dplyr::case_when(rlang::is_empty(x) ~ 1, !rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "2")
# Error in names(message) <- `*vtmp*` : 
#   'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
dplyr::case_when(rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "1", !rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "2")
[1] "1"
```

These messages could for sure be more specific.

---

As mentioned, this does not explain what I think is a bug within the `case_when` source code, specifically `validate_case_when_length`:

```
m <- dplyr:::validate_case_when_length(query, value, fs, error_call = error_call)
```

which erroneously returns 0 in this case.

```
mycase_when <- function (...) 
{
  fs <- dplyr:::compact_null(rlang:::list2(...))
  n <- length(fs)
  error_call <- current_env()
  if (n == 0) {
    abort("No cases provided.", call = error_call)
  }
  query <- vector("list", n)
  value <- vector("list", n)
  default_env <- caller_env()
  quos_pairs <- dplyr:::map2(fs, seq_along(fs), dplyr:::validate_formula, default_env = default_env, 
                     dots_env = current_env(), error_call = error_call)
  for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    pair <- quos_pairs[[i]]
    query[[i]] <- eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env)
    value[[i]] <- eval_tidy(pair$rhs, env = default_env)
    if (!is.logical(query[[i]])) {
      abort_case_when_logical(pair$lhs, i, query[[i]], 
                              error_call = error_call)
    }
  }
  m <- dplyr:::validate_case_when_length(query, value, fs, error_call = error_call)
  
  print(paste('m',m))
  
  print(paste('value', value))
  print(paste('value[[1]][1]', value[[1]][1]))
  out <- value[[1]][rep(NA_integer_, m)]
  replaced <- rep(FALSE, m)
  print(paste('out 1',out))
  for (i in seq_len(n)) {
    out <- dplyr:::replace_with(out, query[[i]] & !replaced, value[[i]], 
                        NULL, error_call = error_call)
    replaced <- replaced | (query[[i]] & !is.na(query[[i]]))
  }
#  print(paste('out 2',out))
  out
}
```

```
mycase_when(rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "Empty", !rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "Not empty")
mycase_when(rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "Empty", !rlang::is_empty(x) ~ x)
mycase_when(rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "Empty", !rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "Not empty")
[1] "m 1"
[1] "value Empty"     "value Not empty"
[1] "value[[1]][1] Empty"
[1] "out 1 NA"
[1] "Empty"
mycase_when(rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "Empty", !rlang::is_empty(x) ~ x)
[1] "m 0"
[1] "value Empty"        "value character(0)"
[1] "value[[1]][1] Empty"
[1] "out 1 "
character(0)
```

Comment: But then that does not explain the unexpected result of `dplyr::case_when(rlang::is_empty(x) ~ "Empty", TRUE ~ x)`, does it?

Comment: True. see the edits